# return from Dialog Activity to MainActivity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, dialog, activity-finish

I have this issue I start an Activity as a Dialog with attribute `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"` so far so good, when I run this Activity I want the user to fill some `EditText`s and then press a button where a background process will be started, now I use `this.setFinishOnTouchOutside(false);` to pervent the user from clicking outside and `finish()` being called, my problem is that I don't get how to `finish()` specifically this DialogLikeActivity, when i call `finish()` after the background process is started the application is close and i want to return to the MainActivity or the Activity that started the DialogLikeActivity (the MainActivity still visible after the `startActivity` or `startActivityForResult()` is called for the DialogLikeActivity, here is what i got:

Code From MainActivity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DialogLikeActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent,0);
```

and the button code in DialogLikeActivity:

```
public void saveClient(View view){
    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
    finish();


}
```

I guess maybe my problem is that MainActivity is not a parent of DialogLikeActivity, in that case it should be? how to make DialogLikeActivity child of MainActivity and if I achieve that would the call for `finish()` in DialogLikeActivity finish the Activity itself and not the app?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english.

EDIT:

[image]

this is the Activity being displayed as a Dialog above the MainActivity

Comment: refer this maybe helpful http://rajeshvijayakumar.blogspot.in/2013/04/alert-dialog-example-in-android.html

Comment: @Aravinth an AlertDialog doesn't work for me, I dont need an "Ok" "cancel" dialog since I just can put a title on it and I need to have the `EditText`s, I need a custom Dialog and that's why I'm using an Activity as a Dialog, thanks anyway.

Comment: You can use an alert dialog and set a custom view on it to achieve the same thing.  This really isn't the point of an Activity either way.  You could try using a DialogFragment.

Comment: @JamesMcCracken i'll try DialogFragment, why isn't the point of an Activity? i want it to be a result Activity, what is wrong with that? i don't want this responsabilty on MainActivity I want other Activity to handle this process, so what is lacking in my process "to fill" the definition of an Activity? i don't understand that.

Comment: There are plenty of better ways to make a Dialog than to try and morph an Activity into one.

Comment: @JamesMcCracken DialogFragment is the way to go, if you want make an answer explaining why use DialogFragment for this case instead of an overlayed Dialog like Activity (i will choose it like correct answer), while implementing the DialogFragment I understand why, maybe i didn't think about DialogFragment cause i still new to Android. Thanks

Comment: No problem.  Fragments are a pretty powerful feature so I would definitely recommend getting familiar with them.  I added an answer as you suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like `DialogFragment` might better suit your needs here.  It has lifecycle methods similar to an `Activity` and can run background tasks within itself, but is actually managed by the activity it is attached to.  There are several types you can use.

Check out the Google documentation on it [HERE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html).